# When I select a page for frontpage, it is blank

Tags: custom-post-types, frontpage

I have some pages on my website if I select a custom post (continents) as the homepage in Settings -> Reading, everything looks fine. If I add another page as the front page, I get and empty page (except for the header and footer) does anyone have any ideas how this can be fixed?

Cheers!

Comment: Maybe sounds funny but do you have a content inside page you choose as homepage at settings page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check in you theme parent folder templates called `front-page.php`, `home.php` and `index.php`. Wordpress in exactly this order is searching for files to use for your homepage. It seems that your template file is broken or has nothing between `get_header()` and `get_footer()`